# Thrift Java: Cannot use reserved language keyword: "alias"

Tags: java, ant, compilation, keyword, thrift

I'm trying to compile thrift code using Ant and seeing the following error:

```
generate-thrift-chained:
[apply] [ERROR:<path_to_thrift_file>/<thrift_file>.thrift:361] (last token was 'alias')
[apply] Cannot use reserved language keyword: "alias"
```

If it matters, I'm on Mac OS X version 10.15.4, Thrift 0.9.3, Ant 1.10.7.
While I understand that using reserved keywords legitimately leads to such problems, this project passes compilation on a different environment, Linux Mint 17.3, with the same Thrift version.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

As per reference from **[Manning|Programmer’s Guide to Apache Thrift](https://livebook.manning.com/book/programmers-guide-to-apache-thrift/chapter-6/v-17/54)**

> Reserved words
>
> The following lexically sorted list of symbols aren’t part of Thrift
>   IDL syntax but may not be used in Thrift IDL for various reasons, many
>   of which are related to output language conflicts.

```
BEGIN, END, __CLASS__, __DIR__, __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, __METHOD__, __NAMESPACE__, abstract, alias, and, args, as, assert, begin, break, case, catch, class, clone, continue, declare, def, default, del, delete, do, dynamic, elif, else, elseif, elsif, end, enddeclare, endfor, endforeach, endif, endswitch, endwhile, ensure, except, exec, finally, float, for, foreach, from, function, global, goto, if, implements, import, in, inline, instanceof, interface, is, lambda, module, native, new, next, nil, not, or, package, pass, print, private, protected, public, raise, redo, rescue, retry, register, return, self, sizeof, static, super, switch, synchronized, then, this, throw, transient, try, undef, unless, unsigned, until, use, var, virtual, volatile, when, while, with, xor, yield
```

**alias** is also in the list